# Smoothness of discrete data

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology

I'm having a hard time putting my question into words, so I made a few pictures.
Look at this plot:

[image: plot a]

Clearly, everyone will agree that these data points are following some nice smooth and continuous function. In the following plot, this is not the case.

[image: plot b]

What I'm looking for, is a word that describes this difference:

> Data set A is much more ??? than data set B.

Is it *smooth*? *Well-behaved* maybe? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would classify these data according to their frequency content. Data set A has only low-frequency components whereas data set B has many high-frequency components.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is "variance." When you look at the data, you fit a curve to it. The curve is smooth, but it's the same curve for both data points.  The difference is how much the data varies form the curve, usually measured by $\frac{1}{n}\sum (f(x)-x)^2$ where $f(x)$ is the equation of the curve. The square root of this quantity is known as the "standard deviation"

You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Comment: This is the best answer. The curve based deviation describes the phenomenon and is a metric at the same time. Maybe a more known term would be mean squared error of approximation. The other metric would be frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "smoother". And the reason will be following:

You can find the Total Variation (TV) of both the data sets. The variation of B will be much more than A.

The formula of total variation is given by,

$TV(u)=\sum_i |u_{i+1}-u_i|$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like data set A is more smooth than data set B because you can easily see the trend that is there. But, the other thing to know that data set B is [most likely] more well-behaved than data set A because you can get from point to point in set B "freely" without "any traffic" by any points, as compared to set A.

Short answer: Data set A is much more smooth than data set B.